# System profiler get me user logged in but not authenticated

Tags: security, symfony, authentication, symfony-2.1

I thought I was finally able to properly manage the login with Symfony 2. But when I get redirected to another page after login, the System Profiler gives me back that the user is logged in but not authenticated and the role: `ROLE_USER`.

If I go back to the login page, however, I correctly that the user is logged in, is authenticated and has the role: `ROLE_USER`

I hope it's a stupid mistake because I started using Symfony recently.
Hope someone has already encountered this problem? Can anyone help me?

**Edit 1**:
This is my security.yml

```
jms_security_extra:
    secure_all_services: false
    expressions: true

security:
    encoders:
        Wearplay\UserBundle\Entity\User: 
            algorithm:        sha1
            encode_as_base64: false
            iterations:       1

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        #ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        user:
            entity: { class: WearplayUserBundle:User }

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern:  ^/
            provider: user
            form_login:
                check_path: login_check
                login_path: login
                default_target_path: /home
            anonymous: true
            remember_me:
                key:      "%secret%"
                lifetime: 2232000 
                path:     /
                domain:   ~ 
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /home

        #secured_area:
        #    provider: user
        #    pattern:    ^/
        #    form_login:
        #        check_path: login_check
        #        login_path: login
        #        default_target_path: home
        #    anonymous: ~

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: http }
        #- { path: ^/logout, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY, requires_channel: https }
        #- { path: ^/home, roles: ROLE_USER, requires_channel: https }
        #
        # You must uncomment the two following rules to restrict access to paths
        # starting with the /_internal prefix to only localhost
        #- { path: ^/_internal/secure, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 127.0.0.1 }
        #- { path: ^/_internal/secure, roles: ROLE_NO_ACCESS }
```

Comment: Did you check Symfony's rule between the `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` and `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED`? [Some documentation about it](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/remember_me.html#forcing-the-user-to-re-authenticate-before-accessing-certain-resources)

Comment: @ThomasPotaire
Thanks. But, once you are logged in and the user gets the role ROLE_USER, automatically, it also gets IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY?

Comment: `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` is granted until the user closes the tab/window (it's probably more complicated than that but you get the idea).

Comment: This seems to me as firewall configuration issue. Can you edit your question to include your `security.yml`?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
jms_security_extra:
    secure_all_services: false
    expressions: true

security:
    encoders:
        Wearplay\UserBundle\Entity\User: 
            algorithm:        sha1
            encode_as_base64: false
            iterations:       1

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER

    providers:
        user:
            entity: { class: WearplayUserBundle:User }

    firewalls:
        login_firewall:
            pattern: ^/login$
            anonymous: ~ 
        main_firewall:
            pattern:  ^/
            provider: user
            form_login:
                check_path: /login_check
                login_path: /login
                default_target_path: /home
            remember_me:
                key:      "%secret%"
                lifetime: 2232000 
                path:     /
                domain:   ~ 
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /home

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: http }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER, requires_channel:https }
```